# Quando um verbo é classificado como transitivo direto ou indireto?

Tags: verbos

Quando um verbo é classificado como verbo transitivo direto ou indireto?
E quando ele é classificado como direto e indireto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um verbo transitivo precisa sempre de complementos, na mesma oração, a não ser que implícitos pelo resto da frase; se for transitivo direto precisa de um complemento direto, se for transitivo indireto, precisa de um complemento direto (ou oblíquo).

Um exemplo de um verbo transitivo indireto é *telefonar*: *Vou telefonar à minha mãe*. Sem a última parte - *à minha mãe* - que desempenha a função de complemento indireto, a frase estaria incorreta, se estivesse isolada.

Comment: "João, espera aqui, vou telefonar" é incorreto? Enquadra-se?

Comment: Não entendi....

Comment: Esta frase está incorreta, pois _telefonar_ é um verbo transitivo e requer a preposição _a_; se no contexto, fosse claro a quem o verbo telefonar se referia, por exemplo, se fosse precedida pela frase _A minha mãe está no hospital_, a frase estaria correta.